# Getting basic Result null on RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

Here is the node.js code and I'm trying convert it to C# with RabbitMQ Client

```
amqp.connect('amqp://xxx-url').then(function(conn) {
  process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
      ch.consume('_816_', doWork, {noAck: true});
      console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    });
```

there is some function Dowork(msg) in the js file

Here is my C# code

```
using (IConnection connection = Connection)
   {
      using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
          {
            var count = channel.MessageCount(queue);
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    
             string x = channel.BasicConsume(queue, false, consumer);                    

             //channel.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                    
              BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queue, true);
              if (result != null)
              {
               string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body.ToArray());
               Console.WriteLine(data);
               }
            }
         }
```

If I try to declare queue I get access denied error, so commented.

I'm always getting null in basic result while it works in js and I continue to get messages.

Basic consume only gives me string, I don't know what is the use of that?

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?